# codeigniter select result array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to select data from my database in codeigniter framework.

My controller

```
public function GetNewestPointers() 
{
  $user_last_login= $this->api_model->getUserLastLogin();
  $result = $this->api_model->getNewestPointers($user_last_login);

  if ($result) 
  { 
    $status = "1";
    $msg = "SUCCESS";
  } 
  else
  {
    $status = "0";
    $msg = "ZERO_RESULT";
  }

  $output = array(
    'status' => $status,
    'message' => $msg,
    'result' => $result
  );

  jsonOutput($output);
}
```

My Model

```
public function getNewestPointers($user_last_login) 
{
    $query = $this->db->query("select * from `pointer_info` where `create_date`> '$user_last_login'");
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function getUserLastLogin() 
{
    $userId = $this->input->get_post('userId');
    $query = $this->db->query("select * from `users` where `id` = '$userId'");

    if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
        return "0";
    else
        return $query->row('last_login');
}
```

My current process  output is

```
"status":"1",
"message":"SUCCESS",
"result":[
    {
        "id":"15",
        "title":"Test Pointer Title",
        "upload_by":"53",
        "create_date":"1413901780",
        "current_status":"approved"
    },
    {
        "id":"14",
        "title":"Test Pointer Title",
        "upload_by":"53",
        "create_date":"1413901750",
        "current_status":"approved"
    }
]
```

But I have need no select data from another table  using above result "id":"14"

and need to show second query data in "item_list" like

```
"status":"1",
"message":"SUCCESS",
"result":[
    {
        "id":"15",
        "title":"Test Pointer Title",
        "upload_by":"53",
        "create_date":"1413901780",
        "current_status":"approved",
         "item_list":[
                {
                    "id":"138",
                    "name":"test",
                    "picture":"",
                    "purchase_status":"no",
                    "total_quantity":"25"
                },
                {
                    "id":"139",
                    "name":"New name2",
                    "picture":"",
                    "purchase_status":"no",
                    "total_quantity":"1"
                }
            ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Well it sounds like you need to join data from a second table.  Your query only queries a single table. Have you made an attempt to join this second table and build the data structure you are looking for?  If so, what problem did you run into?

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample code, I hope it helps.

```
public function GetNewestPointers() 
{
  $user_last_login= $this->api_model->getUserLastLogin();
  $result = $this->api_model->getNewestPointers($user_last_login);

  if ($result) 
  { 
    $status = "1";
    $msg = "SUCCESS";
  } 
  else
  {
    $status = "0";
    $msg = "ZERO_RESULT";
  }

  // sample code
  foreach ($result as $data) 
  {
    $item_list = $this->api_model->getIdData($data['id']);
    $result[$data['id']]['item_list'] = $item_list;
  }

  $output = array(
    'status' => $status,
    'message' => $msg,
    'result' => $result
  );

  jsonOutput($output);
}
```